# Django: How to calculate a context value AFTER rendering template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

The documentation for the render() method says that if a value in the context dictionary is callable, the view will call it just before rendering the template.

The problem is I have a context value that takes a LONG time to calculate and the next page won't be rendered until that is done. I would like to render the next page immediately (without the value), but show a progress bar.

[A lame illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yo0sq.png)

I'm sure there are plenty of ways to do this with AJAX or other solutions, but I would like to do this value calculation with pure Django/python. Is there a way to calculate a value after rendering a page? (Also bringing the question, is a pure Django site limited?)

(I'm not looking for a progress bar solution)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about when you want to start loading the heavy value. Upon reaching page 1?

As you want to avoid ajax, you could include the heavy object as an iframe or if it makes sense as an image or other data format. That way it could be loaded independently and you could set it up to take advantage of browser caching if the value does not change often.

Comment: Upon reaching page 2. Also this isn't an image or file. Just thing of some functions that takes a while to computer a value.

Comment: Then - if ajax is really a no go - I would include an iframe big enough to show the result of the computation. That would load in parallel/independently to the outside page.

Comment: Ok. I was kinda decided from the start that I would have to use ajax. So does Django convention say that context passed into view should always be lightweight?

Comment: No, it's really up to you to decide what is too long for your users to wait and the expectation of the users (is he willing to wait for what he gets). Extensive searches like on e.g. skyscanner through many external services can take 30s but the result justifies it. If you haven't yet, maybe go back a step and see how to improve the heavy calculations.